# Remove package from ppa that is deleted

Tags: apt, ppa

I accidentally deleted an old ppa that I used to install Etcher v1.4.4 before uninstalling the application. Now apt naturally can't find the package and I can't locate the ppa (for this package it seem that the software is now published by another company which only has an AppImage as install option).

How can I safely, and completely, remove the old application?

Comment: There are instructions for connecting to Etcher repositores at [https://www.fossmint.com/etcher-usb-sd-card-bootable-image-creator-for-linux/](https://www.fossmint.com/etcher-usb-sd-card-bootable-image-creator-for-linux/) and at [https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/how-to-install-etcher-on-ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/how-to-install-etcher-on-ubuntu)  Perhaps if you connect to these, you will be able to use them to remove the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find installed etcher package and completely remove it by below commands.

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -i etcher 

sudo apt purge <full package name or exact output of above command>
```

Comment: Will this approach also remove obsolete dependencies?

Comment: You need to run sudo apt autoremove for that.

Comment: That makes sense, but will apt know which packages are obsolete when they are installed by a ppa that no longer exist? (I guess yes, but it would be nice to be sure).

Comment: Apt will detect that and show packages that no longer needed.